# Keeping a computed model field up-to-date via QuerySets

Tags: django, django-queryset

**Preface**:
Let's assume we are working on a DB that stores issues of magazines.
Those issues usually do not have a 'name' per se; instead a whole bunch of attributes (release year, serial number, release months, etc.) will contribute to the name the user may later on identify the issue with.
Depending on the attributes available per issue, this name will be calculated based on a pattern.
For example: an issue from the year `2017` with number `01` will get the name: `2017-01`. An issue from the years `2000` and `2001`, and the months `Jan` and `Feb` will get the name `2000/01-Jan/Feb`.
The attributes can be changed at any time.

It is expected that the user can also do queries based on this name - so simply displaying the computed value (through `__str__`) is not enough.

**What I have done so far**:
For a long time, I actually calculated the name *every* time `__str__` was called on the issue's instance. It was the quick and dirty (and slow) way. 
Querying for the name was very slow and rather complicated and unreliable as it required 'reverse-engineering' the `__str__` method and guessing what the user was trying to search for.

Then I tried a hybrid approach, by using a `_name` model field that is updated if a `_changed_flag` (f.ex. through signals) is set and the instance is instantiated or saved. This still didn't leave me with an up-to-date name on the database table unless I instatiated every instance that needed updating first. Again, slow. And care had to be taken to not end up in infinite recursions upon calling `refresh_from_db` (which recreates the current instance in the background).

**TL:DR**
Right now, I am using a custom QuerySet as a manager for a model with a computed field:

```
class ComputedNameModel(BaseModel):   

    _name = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=False, default=gettext_lazy("No data."))
    _changed_flag = models.BooleanField(editable=False, default=False)

    name_composing_fields = []

    objects = CNQuerySet.as_manager()

    # ... some more methods ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self._name

    class Meta(BaseModel.Meta):
        abstract = True
```

QuerySet:

```
class CNQuerySet(MIZQuerySet):

    def bulk_create(self, objs, batch_size=None):
        # Set the _changed_flag on the objects to be created
        for obj in objs:
            obj._changed_flag = True
        return super().bulk_create(objs, batch_size)

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if any(k.startswith('_name')  for k in kwargs):
            self._update_names()
        return super().filter(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        # it is save to assume that a name update will be required after this update
        # if _changed_flag is not already part of the update, add it with the value True
        if '_changed_flag' not in kwargs:
           kwargs['_changed_flag'] = True
        return super().update(**kwargs)
    update.alters_data = True

    def values(self, *fields, **expressions):
        if '_name' in fields:
            self._update_names()
        return super().values(*fields, **expressions)

    def values_list(self, *fields, **kwargs):
        if '_name' in fields:
            self._update_names()
        return super().values_list(*fields, **kwargs)

    def _update_names(self):
        if self.filter(_changed_flag=True).exists():    
            with transaction.atomic():
                for pk, val_dict in self.filter(_changed_flag=True).values_dict(*self.model.name_composing_fields).items():
                    new_name = self.model._get_name(**val_dict)
                    self.filter(pk=pk).update(_name=new_name, _changed_flag=False)
    _update_names.alters_data = True
```

As you can see the, the boilerplate is real. And I have only cherry picked the QuerySet methods that I know I use for now.
Through signals (for relations) or QuerySet methods, a record's `_changed_flag` is set when anything about it changes. The records are then updated the next time the `_name` field is requested in any way.
It's blazingly fast, as it does not require a model instance (only the model's `classmethod _get_name()`) and works entirely off querysets and in-memory data.

**Question**:
Where to put the call to `_update_names()` such that the names are updated when required without overriding *every single* queryset method?

I have tried putting it in:

- `_clone`: bad things happened. To not end up in recursion hell, you would have to keep track of which clone is trying to update and which are there to simply fetch data for the update. Clones are also created upon initializing your app which has a good (tables are always up-to-date) and a bad side (updating without yet having a need for it, costing time). Not all queryset methods create clones and generally, putting your update check in `_clone` feels *too deep*.
- `__repr__`: Keeps the shell output up-to-date, but not much more. The default implementation takes a slice of the queryset, disabling the ability to filter, so the updating has to be done before `__repr__`.
- `_fetch_all`: Like `_clone`: it runs an update when you may not need it and requires keeping an internal 'you-are-allowed-to-try-an-update' check.

Comment: not sure if fully understand but what's wrong with just override save method and update name with every save?

Comment: Overriding the `save` method does not cover changes made with `queryset.update()` or changes made to related objects.